# Is there any aws datapipeline list-runs equivalent API exist in AWS data pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services

The following list-runs example lists the runs for the specified pipeline.

```
aws datapipeline list-runs --pipeline-id df-00627471SOVYZEXAMPLE
```

Is there any API to lists the runs for the specified pipeline?

Comment: I don't quite get your question. It looks like you're asking for the functionality the command is providing? Can you clarify what you're expecting?

Comment: @Exelian I am looking an api to get all instances of the pipeline run.